# plink Password Over and Over

Tags: git, putty, plink

I am using plink as part of GIT setup and I have setup my remote keys correctly and can connect via Putty.

However, when I attempt to run msysgit and TortiseGit to clone a git directly - enter the path via

> c:\Program Files (x86)\puTTY\plink.exe

I get a window box asking for a password.

Now I have set a pword on my rsa-key - but when I type that password it doesn't work. (i know I can use pageant but it doesn't work because when I enter a pword into that it just says "fatal error hung up")

How can I tell what password or info plink.exe is using as clearly something is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [ticket](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=251) and [this guide](http://web.archive.org/web/20131105160710/http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/05/06/git-ssh-putty-github-unfuddle-the-kitchen-sink.aspx) maybe it will help you.

PS: If your key is password protected you need to have ssh agent (pageant in your case) running with key loaded, otherwise your ssh client wouldn't be able to use your key. The fact that you have a password prompt just means that key-based authentication failed and server accepts password authentication.

PPS: Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497932/msysgit-troubles) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493645/git-fatal-remote-end-hung-up) questions, are you really sure you have same plink used everywhere? I'm not sure all of them would necessarily share configuration, e.g. plink (that comes with putty) and tortoise plink.

Comment: the PS section is incorrect on two counts: 1. pageant does not need to be loaded to use password-protected RSA keys and 2. a password prompt does not necessarily indicate that logging in without a key is possible

Comment: paper1337, I think you're wrong, Nick seems to be getting a _login_ password prompt as a fallback for failed key-authentication, not a key password prompt, and if the server wouldn't accept password-based authentication IIRC it would drop the connection.